# Nginx + Apache trailing slash redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I have a `Nginx` server running on `80` port working as a proxy to `Apache 2.2` which is listening to `127.0.0.1:8080`

When I access `http://hostname/subfolder/` it works great.
When I access `http://hostname/subfolder` it redirects me to `http://hostname:8080/subfolder/` which is wrong.

As far as I see the wrong redirect is returned by Apache but `UseCanonicalName` and `UseCanonicalPhysicalProxy` are both set to `Off`

Any Ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: The problem appears to be with your nginx configuration considering that your access to port 80 without a trailing slash results in a redirect to port 8080. UNLESS your nginx is proxy-ing to Apache and Apache is ordering a redirect.

Comment: I use nginx as a proxy

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this too, and I was able to fix it with a proxy_redirect directive right after my proxy_pass directive in my nginx config:

```
proxy_redirect http://example.com:8080/ http://example.com/
```

This is my full nginx config (In my case, Apache is on port 81 and hosting two sites. I added two site-specific proxy_redirect lines because I'm not sure how to add a single generic one.)

```
server {
    listen 80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/apache-proxy.access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81;

        #fix for apache redirects that include the port number
        proxy_redirect http://nfriedly.com:81/ http://nfriedly.com/;
        proxy_redirect http://misticflame.com:81/ http://misticflame.com/;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 6000;
        proxy_send_timeout 6000;
        proxy_read_timeout 6000;
        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        send_timeout 6000;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_next_upstream error;

    }
}
```

Note: This was for a pre-1.0 version of nginx 5+ years ago. Here's the docs for proxy_redirect for the current version: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Comment: adding proxy_redirect gives the syntax error

Comment: This was on a fairly old version of nginx. I'm no longer using nginx (just static content on github pages for my personal site), but I updated the answer with a link to the current proxy_redirect docs.

Comment: By this way, you still get it slower because of the redirecting

Answer (score 3):

If your ServerName directive on Apache is set to "hostname:8080", remove ":8080" or change it to "hostname:80". You could also add "proxy_set_header Host $host:80"

Comment: I had a similar issue with https URLs without trailing slash. This solution worked perfectly for me, although in case of https the `ServerName` directive has to be set to `https://rootdomain:443`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue long time ago..
As i remember it had to do with the HTTP RFC, slash at the end denotes a directory (/test/)
, no slash at the end its a file (/test)

Long story short, add a rewrite rule that will add a trailing slash to the request, if there is none.

look at [Solved:trailing slash issue with Nginx server](http://purab.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/solvedtrailing-slash-issue-with-nginx-server/)

HTP

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem recently. While the suggested solutions will work, Nginx offers a built-in solution:

```
proxy_redirect default;
```

Documentation at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Here's a full example of how to use it:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080
    proxy_redirect default
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps nginx isn't setting the proxy headers to tell apache what the original request looked like.

In nginx:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

See http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache