# Nginx redirects to port 8080 when accessing url without slash

Tags: nginx

when accessing:
http://example.com/somefolder --> http://example.com:8080/somefolder

I have tried this:

```
 http {
    port_in_redirect off;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your configuration?  Are you proxying to another service behind nginx?

Comment: I believe we are are proxying to apache.  Which configuration files do you want?

Comment: The nginx configuration file that defines the `server` block which contains the `proxy_pass` directive.  What you're probably going to need will be a [`proxy_redirect`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) directive - seeing your config should confirm.

Comment: Note that some browsers cache redirects so when changing `port_in_redirect` from `on` to `off` you may need to restart it.

Comment: @emersion `port_in_redirect` doesn't work at all

Answer (score 37):

I just ran into the same problem and `port_in_redirect off;` actually worked for me, just make sure you use it inside the `server {}` block.

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name example.com;

  port_in_redirect off;
  autoindex on;

  location / {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: Or even use `port_in_redirect` inside `location`.

Comment: worked perfectly for hosting nginx on 8080 behind a load balancer. thank you

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/174297/nginx-apache-trailing-slash-redirect) should fix problem. Add `proxy_redirect` directive right after `proxy_pass` directive

`proxy_redirect http://example.com:8080/ http://example.com/;`

Answer (score 3):

If someone is still experiencing this problem while having apache behind nginx reverse proxy setup, you could try the ff:

```
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port; # <-- this one solved mine
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083;
  }
```

My setup is that I let Apache listen to 127.0.0.1:8083 and let nginx proxy requests to it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my nginx + Apache setup. Apache seems to be redirecting to it's own port (running on 8080), while nginx is on port 80.

In my setup, this made **infinite redirect loop** for *normal* urls:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:80; # Force port 80
```

Instead bind the returning data to port 80, like this:

```
proxy_bind $host:80; # Bind to port 80
```

**Here is my nginx server block:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name _; # Wildcard server

    location / {
        proxy_bind $host:80; # Bind to port 80 << THIS IS THE MAGIC
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host; # Pass host header
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr; # Preserve client IP
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

With this wildcard setup, all requests nginx does not have a server block for is passed on to Apache.

Comment: Doesn't work at all

Answer (score 2):

I think this simple example is enough:

```
location = /somefolder {
    return 302 http://$host:8080/somefolder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else was having this issue - the article here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/strange-nginx-redirects-without-trailing-slash-930876/ solved the problem for me.

I had to add an extra header in the proxy.

Make sure you have the Host set to `$http_host` and also that you have set the `X-Forwarded-Host` to `$http_host` like below:

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;             # <-- make sure this is $http_host
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host; # <-- make sure you set this
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_connect_timeout 90;
proxy_send_timeout 90;
proxy_read_timeout 90;
proxy_buffer_size 16k;
proxy_buffers 32 8k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all

Answer (score 1):

Adding 
`absolute_redirect off;`
in the location block works for me.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.codemongers.com/NginxHttpCoreModule#port_in_redirect

```
syntax: port_in_redirect [ on|off ]
default: port_in_redirect on
context: http, server, location
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have tried this in the http context with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Maybe you should use directive `proxy_set_header` to set the headers' host and location. In my configuration I added `proxy_set_header Location $host:80`;  and all the requests return port 80 now.

Comment: I believe this will break redirects beyond "/" - every redirect would point to $host:80

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by Nginx auto translate relative path to absolute path, right?
There is a way to tell Nginx not translate, you add a space before slash:
`ngx.redirect(" /foo")`

Comment: Please note that this is a question from 3 years ago.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend instead adding this to your server block:

```
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
```

This was when you go to example.com/wp-admin it will go to example.com/wp-admin rather than going to example.com:8080/wp-admin/ and if you are on CloudFlare DNS for instance it will say the site is down.

I'm using Ubuntu, Nginx and Varnish and this works perfectly now rather than disabling port_in_redirect.

To add, be sure to to restart nginx after:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```