# how force a website to run on port 80 with reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, configuration, port-forwarding

I have a website in a private subnet, which is working on apache 2.4 on port 8090 with reverse proxy to nginx 1.18 on port 80, meaning all static content operating nginx, and all dynamic - apache.
I found that the website behaves like it's different websites on different web-servers. My point is to restrict access to 8090 and forward requests to 80.
here's configs below:
apache virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
        ServerName gamingwiki.shprd.lan
        ServerAlias www.gamingwiki.shprd.lan
        ServerAdmin admin@gamingwiki.shprd.lan

        DocumentRoot /opt/wiki

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

ports.conf

```
Listen 8090

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

nginx website.vhost

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name gamingwiki.shprd.lan;
        #index doku.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        #forbid access to data,conf,bin,lib folders
        location ~ /(data|conf|bin)/ {
                deny all;
        }

        #forbid access to hidden files starts with .dot
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                #access_log off;
                #log_not_found off;
        }

        # First attempt to serve requests as file, then as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        location / {
                root /opt/wiki/;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }       

}
```

and here's proxy.conf

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
``
```

Comment: That looks fine. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider i mean port 8090 shouldn't be available to access from browser, it loading the website the as on the 80
i've changed ports.conf to "Listen 127.0.0.1:8090" for Apache. But in perfect conditions, when i accessing port 8090 in the browser, i have to be redirected to port 80

Comment: Have you tried this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/174297/nginx-apache-trailing-slash-redirect

Comment: I wouldn't bother about port 8090 more than binding it to the loopback interface.